# How to check if a value from an array exists in an MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I want to check if none of the days exist in **`custom_tag`** table of my database but the following code doesn't work. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
$tag_checker = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT tag FROM custom_tag" );
$days = array( 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday' );

if( empty( array_intersect( $tag_checker, $days ) ) ) :
// then do something
endif;
```

Comment: Why not do it in the query rather than php?

Comment: use where not in in your query instead of using php

Comment: *"but my following code doesn't work."* - Doesn't work how? you didn't say and we don't know what the schema looks like for this.

Comment: Thanks Cemal and Ram-Kesavan this sorted it

Answer (score 0):

```
$days = array( 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday' );
$tag_checker = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT tag FROM custom_tag WHERE tag IN ('" .implode("','", $days). "')");


if( empty( $tag_checker ) ) :
    echo 'hello';
endif;
```